# Flask Attribute error with unpickling

Tags: python, flask, pickle

I am trying to load a pickle and display some data through a Flask app. The structure I am following is as follows.

**package1.py**

```
class myclass:
    #do something
m = myclass()
pickle.load(m,filehandle)
```

**package2.py**

```
from package1 import myclass
def query_processor(params):
    x = pickle.load(filehandle)
    #do stuff on x using params
    return results
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(query_processor(params)) #Works as expected
```

**flaskapp.py**

```
import package2

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    result = package2.query_processor(params)
    return render_template(template_name,form=form,msg=result)
```

Inside the flaskapp, I am getting an error like :

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'myclass' on <module '__main__' from <flask_path>
```

Is there some way to fix this issue? Can someone please explain why I am having this error?

Answer (score 1):

In order to unpickle you need to have the very same module and package structure compared to the point in time you've pickled the object.

Your exception suggests you had the class defined in the module you've run as program, thus it had not the name of the *.py file but the name `__main__`.  And when trying to unpickle it from the Flask application another module is the `__main__` module, a module which doesn't contain the `myclass` class object.

So the easiest fix would be using another module as program when *creating* the pickle.  That module has to import `package1` or at least `myclass` from `package1`.